# Cleaning up a file in linux using a script like sed or awk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk, sed

I have a file that has been created using an expect script to pull some information off of an iot device. the file looks like this:

```
1: 4.9 A
1.99 kW
39483.3 kWh
1.99 kW
1: 1.99 kW
```

I need to remove everything but the number values so the '1: ', ' A', ' kW' and the ' kWh' need to be removed. Ive spent a couple hours trying to get sed or awk to do what I need but i'm not familiar with them and after a bunch of guides I still couldn't get it working properly. Any help from someone who is more familiar with these tools would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show your attempts please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is probably what you're really trying to do:

```
$ awk '{print $(NF-1)}' file
4.9
1.99
39483.3
1.99
1.99
```

i.e. just print the 2nd-last field from each line.